# How do I parse thru an object in the meta_value column

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I would like some help iterating through an object that is stored in the `meta_value` column of my `wp_postmeta` table.

I have ID's stored in the column and I would like to use those ID's in an inner `SELECT` that will go and get the Page Title that is associated with each ID.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_status, p.post_type, pm.meta_key,      pm.meta_value
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm
WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id
AND pm.meta_key = topic_related_topics
AND pm.meta_value != ''
ORDER BY p.post_title, p.post_type desc
```

Here is an example of what is brought back:

```
1313,ADIPIC ACID,draft,post,topic_related_topics,
    a:5: 
    {i:0;s:3:"961";
    i:1;s:4:"1313";
    i:2;s:3:"975";i:
```

Basically I need to know the title that is associated with ID 961.  The title resides in the `wp_posts` table.

Comment: Please explain meta_value format.

Comment: Hi @seahawk, the meta_value you see in the question is a serialized array.

Answer (score 2):

The value you are seeing in the database is an array that has been serialized to a string by PHP. The `i` stands for "integer" and the `s` stands for "string", with the number following the `s` indicating how long the string is. In this case, even though "961" is an integer, it is being stored as a string in the first place of a an array with 5 elements (it looks like you chopped the last 2 off).

There isn't a good way to unserialize the data in SQL, so you will need to do it in PHP and then make a second query to get the title. You can use the WordPress function [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) to convert it back into an array.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "your sql....";
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $your_args ) );
foreach( $rows as $row ){
    // convert to an array
    $ids = maybe_unserialize( $row->meta_value );
    // loop through the array
    foreach( $ids as $id ){
        // fetch the titles
        $sql = "SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d";
        $title = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $id ) );
    }
}
```

A more standard way of doing it would be to just use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to fetch the array, and have WordPress handle the serialization internally. The other big advantage here is that if you are using caching, support for it is already built into these functions.

Lastly if you *do* want to be able to fetch it all in a single SQL query, you will need some additional logic, likely hooked to the saving of the meta value. In addition to having it save as an array, you can grab the single value you want to JOIN on and save it in its own meta_key. With a single value you can then join the posts table to the postmeta to accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you that helps.  I was stuck trying to work it out in the sql statement.  Your solution works for me!